# asp.net Repeater - get Reference to current Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater, dataitem

I am using Asp.net 4.5, C#.
I have a reapter that has some DataSource Bind to it:

```
  <asp:Repeater ItemType="Product" ID="ProductsArea" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                ...  
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Inside this repeater, I would like a refrence to the current Iterated Item.
I know I can use `<%#Item%>` and that I can Use `<%#Container.DataItem%>`. If I want to get to a field, I can use `<%#Item.fieldName%>` or Eval it.

But I want to make a condition on a field, How can I get the refrence to the #Item in order to do something like this:

```
<% if (#Item.field>3)%>, <%if (#Container.DataItem.field<4)%>
```

I would acautley would like to have a refrence like this
`<%var item = #Item%`> and than to use it whenever I need.

Ofcourse the syntax above is invalid, How to achieve this properley?

Comment: I'd use `ItemDataBound` instead. That makes the code much more readable, maintainable and robust(compile time type safety).

Comment: How to? Im not familiar with this

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `ItemDataBound` instead. That makes the code much more readable, maintainable and robust(compile time type safety).

```
protected void Product_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // presuming the source of the repeater is a DataTable:
        DataRowView rv = (DataRowView) e.Item.DataItem;
        string field4 = rv.Row.Field<string>(3); // presuming the type of it is string
        // ...
    }
}
```

Cast `e.Item.DataItem` to the actual type. If you need to find a control in the `ItemTemplate` use `e.Item.FindControl` and cast it appropriately. Of course you have to add the event-handler:

```
<asp:Repeater OnItemDataBound="Product_ItemDataBound" ItemType="Product" ID="ProductsArea" runat="server">
```

Comment: But this is Server sided. I need to use it on the Page side like this <%if (#Item.BonusType==Enum.BounusTypes.50Percent){%> you get 50% off!<%}%>

Comment: @Programer: that is also executed on serverside. You can get the same code in a much more readable manner. But you have to show more of what you're trying to do and the controls involved, otherwise i cannot show you a complete example.

Comment: I know, But I want it to be on the dynamic page not in a function. how do I print to the html if condition is valid in you way?

Comment: @Programer: then you have to wait for another answer. I don't know and don't want to know how you can do something like that with inline aspx. That's more like classic ASP than ASP.NET.